# User owns a model and other users can join this model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to creat an application where a User can create a Room and is the only owner of it. Other users should be able to join a Room, just one at the time and only they should be able to see what is happening in this Room.

So i created a controller rooms_controller and the model Room.

Btw I'm using devise to handle all the Userstuff.

So what should i put into the user.rb file? has_one :room? belongs_to :rooms?
How can users join a model?

Answer (score 0):

You can design the models this way. You can actually have two types of users: `Owner` and `User` and they can inherit from the `BaseUser` where `BaseUser` being the class with all the common user attributes.

And, your model associations can look like this:

```
class BaseUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # all the common user attributes here
end

class Owner < User
  has_one :room
end

class User < BaseUser
  has_many :rooms
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`owner` has one `room` and `room` belongs to `owner`.
`user` has many `rooms` and `room` belongs to `user`.

You have to add `owner_id` and `user_id` in your `rooms` table.
You can also have a `user_type` column in your `base_users` table to indicate what type of user is this (i.e. `owner` or `user`).

Also, take a look at the [cancancan gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) which is an authorization Gem for Ruby on Rails application. You will need to have different types of abilities for example: owner will be able to create the room but user can't create the room, they can only join. You need to handle these things using authorization.

Comment: is it possible that the user automaticaly becomes an 'owner' when he created a room?

Comment: It will not happen automatically. But you can that happen. When a room is created, you can associate an owner to that room, but many users can be associated (i.e. may user can join) to that room.

Comment: My whole application is build on devise. Is cancancan rly necessary?

Comment: Devise is for authentication. Cancancan is for authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Does a User have an one.to-one relationship with Room? In that case User has_one Room. Or can a User create many Rooms? A User can join a Room, if, for example, there is a Rooms_Visitors table where the RoomId and the UserId identify a row.

Its hard to answer without knowing your broad use case.
I advice that you study a bit on SQL relations, then the answer for your use case will become clear to you.

Comment: A users should be able to create a room, this user is the owner of this room and should not be able to create or join other rooms. Every other user, that's not an owner should be able to join a room, just one.

Comment: Then, if a User cannot be both Owner and Visitor, the inheritance strategy suggested by @K M Rakibul Islam is what I would go for too. I would just change the schema this way:   

# A user of our system
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # all the common user attributes here, like id and stuff
end

class Owner < User
  has_one :room
end

class Visitor< BaseUser
  has_one :rooms
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  has_many : visitor
end

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, couldnt find how to type the schema as code